# This SQL gives an ORA-12704 and any suggestions on how to fix

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 
CASE when length(attr2) > 0
        then attr2
        ELSE '-'
        END AS attr2
from vdata

desc vdata

attr2 nvarchar(30)
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: could you please edit your question with expected output, and mark off your code so it is readable?

Comment: cast `'-'` to nvarchar by using `n'-'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select coalesce(attr2, to_nchar('-')) from vdata
```